# Python Missing Values Strategy

Tags: python

I'm reading packets from RF transceiver, where each packet has unique ID. It can happen that some of the packets are not received.

In post processing analysis, I am adding dummy packets with indicator (column PR) that they are not received but artificially added to enable packet reception rate plot. Sample of the file looks like this:

```
TS,RxID,RSSI,SNR,PR
.....
.....
252,1,-105,16,1
504,2,-105,17,1
756,3,-105,17,1
1008,4,,,0
1260,5,-105,16,1
1512,6,-106,16,1
1764,7,,,0
2016,8,-105,16,1 
....
....
```

What should I add for RSSI and SNR (which are empty in current file sample, when PR is 0) to be able to plot RSSI and SNR column with gaps where packets were not received. I tried inserting None, and empty string, but always get the same error:

```
could not convert string to float: 'None'
```

The code that fills dummy packets:

```
inputFile = 'd:\\f1.txt'
outputFile = 'd:\\f2.txt'
timeStamp = 0       
timeConstant = 252  
packetID = 1         
numOfPackets = 20023     

with open(outputFile,'w') as g:
    while (packetID <= numOfPackets):
        noPacket = 1
        with open(inputFile, 'r') as f:           

            for i, line in enumerate(f):  
                line = line.strip() 
                line = line.split(',')
                currentLine = line
                auxLine = line
                if (int(currentLine[1]) == packetID):
                    noPacket = 0
                    auxLine[0] = str(int(packetID * timeConstant))
                    auxLine.append('1\n')
                    auxLine = ','.join(auxLine)
                    g.write(auxLine)
                    break

            if (noPacket == 1):    
                auxLine[0] = str(int(packetID * timeConstant))
                auxLine[1] = str(packetID)
                auxLine[2] = str('') #this is the part where the value for RSSI has to be written 
                auxLine[3] = str('') #this is the part where the value for SNR has to be written 
                auxLine.append('0\n')
                auxLine = ','.join(auxLine)
                g.write(auxLine)

            packetID += 1

        f.close()

g.close()
```

The code that plots RSSI (the same as for SNR):

```
results = pd.read_csv('d:/f2.txt', delimiter = ',')
rssi = results['RSSI']
plt.plot(rssi,'g', linestyle = 'dotted', label='RSSI')
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: You're not using `float()`, so where is that error at? Add the full traceback

Comment: Btw, `f.close()` is not needed. The file already closed after `with open()` usage

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter these missing values, in such a case I would probably use "nan" to indicate that case. Depending on the functionality of the plot function you might need to remove these values from the rssi list before calling plot.

Comment: I have to plot RSSI from several different files to compare them. When the packet is not received there has to be the gap on the plot. All files are aligned in terms of packet id (with code provided) to enable comparison. The only thing is that I dont know how to plot those gaps.

Comment: Having these 'nan' in the list, it depends from the plot function how this case is handled. In MATLAB you would get the desired gaps - but I do not know what library you are using here and so its difficult to give an advice.